# Python generator confusing me

Tags: python, scope, namespaces, generator

Why this happended? I am getting confused.
In the first case, I define `chunked_test_list` by a list conprehension. The output is as expected.
But, in the next case, I define `chunked_test_list` as a generator. And then, when I look through it with a for loop, just the first loop give me the expected result, and the rest is EMPTY list. I got confused..
And, in the last case, I change the variable name from `test_list` to `test_list_1` in for loop, and then it turns out run as expected. Oh, I got more confused.

```py
test_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
step = 2

chunked_test_list = [test_list[x: x + step] for x in range(0, len(test_list), step)]
for test_list in chunked_test_list:
    print('test_list', test_list)

# >>>output
# test_list [1, 2]
# test_list [3, 4]
# test_list [5, 6]
# test_list [7, 8]
```

```py
test_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
step = 2

chunked_test_list = (test_list[x: x + step] for x in range(0, len(test_list), step))  # GENERATOR
for test_list in chunked_test_list:  # the variable name `test_list` is SAME to list above
    print('test_list', test_list)

# >>>output
# test_list [1, 2]
# test_list []
# test_list []
# test_list []
```

```py
test_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
step = 2

chunked_test_list = (test_list[x: x + step] for x in range(0, len(test_list), step))  # GENERATOR
for test_list_1 in chunked_test_list:  # the variable name `test_list` is NOT same to list above
    print('test_list_1', test_list_1)

# >>>output
# test_list_1 [1, 2]
# test_list_1 [3, 4]
# test_list_1 [5, 6]
# test_list_1 [7, 8]
```

Comment: You're using the same variable name (`test_list`) for the initial list and for the loop variable. If you use a different variable name in the loop, it works correctly.

Comment: Yes. But if I use list not generator, and it turned to print out the expected result, even if the variable names are the same. Could u explain why?

Comment: if youre running this all at once, then you're trying to make the generator with test_list, which is not the one you defined, but rather the last element of the list from the previous loop...just use a different variable name, this looks like bad practice - and evidently is leading you to errors

Comment: If you make a generator I would expect.a function with a yield statement. I cannot see one ...

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen you can make generators in a list-comprehension like manner

Comment: Yeah, generators can be made by this manner. Indeed, duplicate variable name is a bad pratise which leaded me to errors.

Comment: When using a list in a for loop, the initial sequence is determined at the start of the loop. Updating the underlying list has no impact. When using an iterator, the next element in the loop is determined at each iteration so changing the underlying list while looping _does_ have impact.

Comment: what @Mike67 said

Comment: @Mike67. I found the PEP that says so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you are seeing is formally caused by the binding of names in a generator, as laid out in [PEP289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#early-binding-versus-late-binding).

The list comprehension `chunked_test_list = [test_list[x: x + step] for x in range(0, len(test_list), step)]` refers to `test_list`, but creates a list of sliced lists immediately. Rebinding the name `test_list` as the subsequent loop variable does not affect the elements of the list `chunked_test_list`.

Now let's take a look at the generator

```
chunked_test_list = (test_list[x: x + step] for x in range(0, len(test_list), step))
```

The loop expression `range(0, len(test_list), step)` is evaluated immediately. The range is created as soon as the line runs, and you can see that it uses the expected `len(test_list)` by the number of iterations.

At the same time, the body of the generator loop, `test_list[x: x + step]`, is evaluated every time the outer `for` loop calls `next`. The loop `for test_list in chunked_test_list:` effectively performs the assignment `test_list = gen.next()` at each iteration. During the first call to `next`, `test_list` is bound to its original value. You see the first element of the generator print as expected. As soon as the call returns however, the name `test_list` is bound to the result of `next`. Since none of the return values are long enough to support the index generated by the range, you see empty lists.

When you rename the loop variable in the generator to `test_list_1`, `test_list` does not get rebound, and the loop completes without conflict.

Comment: I have difficulty understanding ur explaination after reading lotta times. And then I opened my editor to debug it, then I found the truth and knew what u said. It is actually the trick of naming conflict and feature of iterator, am I right?

Comment: @Gorgine. Exactly. As you get better at pyhon, you will understand more. Basically, you overwrote the name